# unable to connect essbase from obiee 12c

Tags: oracle, obiee, hyperion, essbase

I'm using obiee 12.2.1.3.0(in one machine) and essbase 11.2.5.0(another machine) and I have open rpd in online and when I try access essbase I'm getting the error as below screen shot

[image]

Essbase server - is server machine name where essbase got installed

I am able to connect the same essbase with power BI from my machine, I can't able to connect it with only through OBIEE.

Please help me on resolving the issue

Comment: There's no "error on below screen shot". Or, at least, I don't see any.

Comment: @Littlefoot sorry, please find the updated screen shot

Comment: Error is here now, but in vain (as far as I'm concerned) as I have no idea what it means. Google doesn't know it either, unfortunately ... I hope someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Comment: @Littlefoot, thanks for ur reponse, I'm stuck on this issue for more than a month, from obiee it's not even trying hit the essbase server, do we need to something while installing obiee for essbase

Comment: @Littlefoot is way I gave server name is right?